# NgOnInit - IonWillEnter Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having problems when loading component in ionic5/angular app. I receive the following error:

> "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null"

when the initialization code is in the IonViewWillEnter method.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.appDataService.changePageName('Visita.Detalle.title');

  this.controles = this.route.snapshot.data['controles'];
  this.visita = this.route.snapshot.data['visita'];

  this.idVisita = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  this.authService.getUserSubject().subscribe(
    data => this.currentUser = data,
    error => console.log(error)
  );

  console.log(this.controles)
  for(let control of this.controles){

    //Convierto tipo de datos firestore en date
    if(control.fecha.seconds) control.fecha = new Date(control.fecha.seconds * 1000)

    this.ubicacionService.obtenerUbicacion(control.ubicacionId).subscribe(
      data => {
        control.ubicacion = data.nombre
        console.log(control)
      },
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
  }  

  console.log(this.controles)
  console.log(this.visita)
}
```

When using same code in ngOnInit problem disappear. But NgOnIt do not trigger when coming back to page, which is a desired behavior.

I assume problem is related to this part of the template:

```
          <ion-fab-button color="warning" [routerLink]="['/irregularidad','establecimiento', visita?.establecimientoId ,'alta']">
        <ion-icon name="alert-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-fab-button>
```

Comment: try move your code for reading the route params to the constructor

Comment: Wouldn't It run only once that way?

Comment: yes same as when u run it in ionViewEnter and ngOnInit. exmple from Angular: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Comment: Unfortunately, as commented, I require to run this method on navigating back too.

Comment: you can set the route on the back button as well. So you will get your params